# Convert tif files to gif with specific order with imagemagick in python script

Tags: python, imagemagick

update:
os.system gave the error message, which looks very strange. Why there is not C: before the image path? Absolutely there are files in the folder.

`` convert.exe: unable to open image `\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\1.tif',': No
such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\
test\\1.tif',' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
convert.exe: unable to open image `\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\2.tif',': No
such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\
test\\2.tif',' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
convert.exe: unable to open image `\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\3.tif']': No
such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\
test\\3.tif']' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.
convert.exe: no images defined `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\animated.gif' @ error/
convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3147. ``

I would like to use imagemagick to convert tif files to gif with given orders using below python script. However, it seems like that when I pass the images list to imagemagick command line string `convert -alpha deactivate -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 {} {}animated.gif'.format(images, path)`, the imagemagick can not recognize the images list.

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\"
filenames = ["2.tif", "1.tif", "3.tif"]
images = [path + filename for filename in filenames]
os.system('convert -alpha deactivate -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 {} {}animated.gif'.format(images, path))
```

Normally, I can use command line `convert -alpha deactivate -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 *.tif animated.gif'` to convert things of current folder. But like this way I can not specify the tif file orders as what I want. It will convert files as `1.tif`, `2.tif`, `3.tif` order to final gif.

So is there any way to pass python list to imagemagick command line string?

Comment: @unutbu it gave the error message:

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my question.

After some dig, I found that imagemagick command line can accept arguments like
`convert -alpha deactivate -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 2.tif 1.tif 3.tif animated.gif'`, then it is easy to give a solution like below:

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test\\"
filenames = ["2.tif", "1.tif", "3.tif"]
images = " ".join([path + filename for filename in filenames])
os.system('convert -alpha deactivate -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 {} {}animated.gif'.format(images, path))
```

Using join function to join list to a string, and pass it to os.system, everything will be fine.